# Latex Beamer - white space in navigation after partpage

Tags: beamer, parts, navigation

I am giving a long talk and would like to split the presentation in several parts. The presentation is based on a theme with navigation bars (I like the small circles there), say for instance the Frankfurt theme. Now I notice the following behaviour:

1. As long as there is no \frame{\partpage} included the naviagtion bar ist just fine.
2. Using \frame{\partpage} directly after \part leads to white spaces in the top left corner of navigation bar (see for instance the white space over section name "P2 / Sec 1" in the MWE below). So the navigation bar will be shifted to the right.

Is there a possibility to remove these white spaces?

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usetheme{Frankfurt} 
\begin{document}
\part[Part 1]{Part 1}
    \frame{\partpage}
    \section[P1 / Sec 1]{Part 1 - Section 1}
        \begin{frame}{Header}
            Text
        \end{frame}
    \section[P1 / Sec 2]{Part 1 - Section 2}
        \begin{frame}{Header}
            Text
        \end{frame}
\part[Part 2]{Part 2}
    \frame{\partpage}
    \section[P2 / Sec 1]{Part 2 - Section 1}
        \begin{frame}{Header}
            Text
        \end{frame}
    \section[P2 / Sec 2]{Part 2 - Section 2}
        \begin{frame}{Header}
            Text
        \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Here are two screenshots identifying white space. The left screenshot shows the top left corner of a frame of part 1, where everything is just fine - the first circle is aligned perfectly. The reight screenshot shows the top left corner of a frame of part 2 - please notice the circle moved to the right - the aligment of part to is different relative to part 1.

[image: No white space.]
[image: White Space visible.]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! I cannot reproduce these observations on my up-to-date TeXLive 2018 distribution. Note that this does not mean you are doing something wrong or so, I just want to mention that this issue seems not to exist on all distributions.

Comment: Dear marmot, thank you for the prompt response. I am using miktex 2.9 - I will try this with TeXLive on another computer today.

Comment: Did you update your distribution(s) recently?

Comment: I just updated miktex but no changes regarding the white space.

Comment: @The_Lucky_Luke Could you please tell us which version of beamer you are using and which engine you use for compiling?

Comment: @samcarter: I work with miktex 2.9, beamer packaged on 04.09.2018, and I use sublimetext 3 (build 3176) with latextools. Probably there is no issue with sublime text - I compiled the file with TEXworks and it yields the same result.

Comment: @The_Lucky_Luke Which engine do you use for compiling? Pdflatex or something else? Can you please include a screenshot of the whitespace you see?

Comment: I use pdflatex. I will add the screenshot to the question.

Comment: (@marmot) With my up-to-date TeXLive 2018 distribution, I can reproduce the problem...

Comment: @The_Lucky_Luke Ah, you mean "black space" :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this boils down to the same issue as https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/456

---

Workaround based on https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/461

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usetheme{Frankfurt} 

\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{section}{part}
\makeatletter

\makeatletter
\AtBeginPart{\beamer@tocsectionnumber=0}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\part{Part 1}

\begin{frame}{Header}
\end{frame}

\section{P1 - S1}
\begin{frame}{Header}
\end{frame}

\part{Part 2}

\begin{frame}{Header}
Shift visible here
\end{frame}

\section{P2 - S1}
\begin{frame}{Header}
\end{frame}

\section{P2 - S2}
\begin{frame}{Header}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Problem solved! @samcarter: Sorry for confusing - you are right, actually it is a black space :-)